# how to access Qt MainWindow members

Tags: qt

In my project, I want to call a variable `QImage image` generated in the `mainwindow.h`, in other class files, e.g., called `SegSetupDialog.h`. Here the `image` is loaded by clicking a pushbutton in `mainwindow.ui`, and the `SegSetupDialog` is a `QDialog`, which pops up by clicking one pushbutton in `mainwindow.ui`.

I tried to use a signal-slot connection to send `qimage` of `mainwindow` to `SegSetupDialog` as follows.

For Class MainWindow:

```
SegSetupDialog *segsetup;

if(image.isNull()==false)
  {
        emit sendImgData(image);
        qDebug()<<"sendImgData emitted!";

        if(segsetup==NULL) segsetup = new SegSetupDialog();
        connect(this, SIGNAL(sendImgData(QImage)),segsetup,SLOT(getImgData(QImage)),Qt::QueuedConnection);
   }
```

In SegSetupDialog::getImgData

```
void SegSetupDialog::getImgData(QImage qimage)
{
    qImg = qimage;
    qDebug()<<"qimage received!";
}
```

The above connection seems not to work since the qDebug message in `getImgData` is not printed out. Anyone can help check something wrong with codes, or suggest other methods for accessing `image` of `mainwindow`? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the signal/slot connection **before** you emit the signal. Connections are done once, usually in the constructor.

However, you should probably do the `connect()` in the constructor of `SegSetupDialog` instead of the `MainWindow` one. It's `SegSetupDialog` that wants to be notified about image data updates, so you should establish the connection there.

Also, to make sure the signals and slots are specified correctly, don't use Qt 4 `connect()` calls. Use Qt 5 ones that are checked at compile-time:

```
connect(this, &MainWindow::sendImgData,
        segsetup, &SegSetupDialog::getImgData, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

(Of course change it appropriately if you move it to the SegSetupDialog constructor.)

Comment: Thanks! I put the connection in the constructor of MainWindow, thus solving the problem. I was not aware of the connection of Qt4 and Qt5. Can you expand on their syntax difference a little bit?

Comment: @jingweimo The new syntax allows the compiler to check the signal and slot functions during compilation time. So if your connection is wrong, it will catch it when you try and compile your code. With the old syntax, this is not the case. Connection errors will only show up when running the code. Another feature of the new syntax is you can use a lambda function instead of a slot. This is useful if the code of the slot would be very short (like just one line). And yet another benefit is that the function you connect to does not actually have to be a slot. It can be a regular member function.

Comment: @jingweimo More information here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html

Comment: @jingweimo Finally, if you have existing connections using Qt4 syntax, you can automatically convert most of them if you're using Qt Creator. Right-click on the `connect` call, and in the menu that appears select "Refactoring" and then "Convert to Qt 5 connection".

Comment: It is very convenient to do so.